# Realm Swift : Update an object inside a closure

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, realm

For the sake of the question, here's a simple example (with a few shortcuts) :

```
class Foo: Object {
  dynamic var id: Int = 0
  [...]
}

class Bar: Object {
  dynamic var id: Int = 0
  dynamic var foo: Foo?

  convenience required init(data: AnyObject) {
    self.init()
    self.id = data.id as! Int

    if let foo_id = data.foo_id as? Int {
      // Function querying the remote database and returning an object
      Foo.get(foo_id) { (foo) -> Void in
        self.foo = foo // Foo object assigned, as expected
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If i'm doing the `self.foo = foo` in the closure of the `get()` function, i got an exception :

> exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.'

So if i'm adding a realm.write around it, as asked by the previous exception :

```
...
Foo.get(foo_id) { (foo) -> Void in
  let realm = Realm(path: Realm.defaultPath)
  realm.write {
    self.foo = foo
  }
}  
...
```

This time I get a new one :

> exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Can not add objects from a different Realm'

I'm stuck and i can't figure out what Realm is wanting from me here, the doc isn't helping.

I'm not that used to Realm, so i suppose I got something wrong on how it works, but i don't know what.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you performing this on an object that has already been saved in *ANY* other Realm? Something else than `Realm.defaultPath`? The first exception is obvious - either do `beginWriteTransaction()` -> write -> `commitWriteTransaction()` or the block that you mentioned. The other exception happens when you're trying to update the object in a **wrong** realm, than the one you've already saved it to.

Comment: I have only one Realm, i'm using the default one. I was thinking that could be related to using `self` in the closure after the object has been initialized?

Comment: I also tried the `self.realm.write() { ...}`, but `self.realm` is an optional and is nil when trying to write my object, so i see no point to using this one

Comment: Yes, that's correct, sorry for that one, I realized the moment I posted the comment.

Comment: A wild one - wrap the whole database query in write closure - `Foo.get`

Comment: Interesting ! I've just test it but unfortunately same exception occurs

Comment: Well...I think you probably know yourself that this isn't really a best practice approach - preferably you should have all the data for the object ready when you're inializing it **OR** have the database query in a separate method outside of the initializer...

Comment: Sorry that sounded really patronizing. Just giving you my opinion...

Comment: Actually, no i didn't know i was doing a mistake, but i'm glad to learn if it says nicely :) Fact is i need to retrieve an image from a server link to this object, that's the reason why i'm doing like that, when initializing it. Since it looks like impossible and wrong to do it this way, i will follow your advice and take a better approach. Do you think i should close this question, or would you want to put an answer and i will accept it?

Comment: I posted the approach I consider clean. Try it and let me know if you encounter with any problems or questions.

Comment: self.realm will return the realm an instance is associated with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so the problem is this - you're trying to open `write()` session when the object is not saved in Realm in the initializer itself and my guess is that the framework is not really happy about it.

My recommendation for the approach is this:

1. Set the values that you know before obtaining the data from the database in the object and the rest that you don't set either to some default values or set them as optional values.
2. Save the object to the realm and then invoke the download in closure (asynchronously of course) - which will take the object in the closure and because by that time the object will have been saved in realm, you will be able to directly access `savedObject.realm` and you will be able to write correctly without exceptions.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it's correct, but I don't fully agree with your recommendations. I posted another answer which should provide OP with a different perspective. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr; you can't assign a persisted Realm object to a property of an unpersisted Realm object

It would be useful to know what `Foo.get(_:)` is doing. My guess would be that it creates a persisted Realm object (perhaps even on a different thread), whereas the `Bar` object is never persisted (calling `super.init()` will just create a standalone object, unlinked to any Realm).

If my assumptions about `Foo.get(_:)` are correct, just create a standalone `Foo` in that function instead. Then you'll be able to set it as `Bar`'s property outside of any write transaction.